# sfml platformer error: missing type specifier - int assumed

Tags: c++, sfml

Hey im trying to check to see if my bounding box from my player class is colliding with the bounding box of my map tiles. however it is coming up with that error. i have a definition in my map.h called Player playermap; with an include of my player h. i then go onto check if they both intersect by saying if mapplayer.boundingbox.intersects(platformboundingbox) then collision occured. take a look and any insight would be much appreciated

here is a part of my map class

```
if(mapVector[i][j] == 1)
                         {
                            sprite.SetImage(BlockImage);
                            sprite.SetPosition(j * BLOCKSIZE, i * BLOCKSIZE);
                            platformBoundingBox.Top = sprite.GetPosition().y - 5;
                            platformBoundingBox.Bottom = sprite.GetPosition().y;
                            platformBoundingBox.Left = sprite.GetPosition().x - 5;
                            platformBoundingBox.Right = sprite.GetPosition().x;
                            Window.Draw(sprite);    
                            if(mapPlayer.boundingBox.Intersects(platformBoundingBox))
                                cout<<"collision occured";
                         }
```

here is where it comes up with the error in my map.h file

```
Player mapPlayer;
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the _complete_ error message, _all_ of the messages, and please also point out on which line in the code they are about. It would also be good if you included the _definitions_ of all involved classes/structures that you made.

Comment: I have shown where the error comes up. at the end Player mapPlayer. and the two classes involved. map and player. i just want to use the bounding box from player in my map class. and that is error. apart from the error code "error c4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note c++ dies not support default-int.

Comment: But what is `boundingBox`? What is `platformBoundingBox`? And what version of SFML?

Comment: Yeah sorry i should of included them details. 

sfml 1.6 and they are both sf::Rect<float>

Comment: Are you doing `using namespace sf;` in the source file, or an included header file?

Comment: Yes in my map header file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your

```
using namespace sf;
```

This will make your variable `Window` clash with the [`sf::Window`](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/1.6/classsf_1_1Window.php) class.

Either use e.g.

```
this->Window.Draw(...);
```

Or (what I recommend) stop with the `using` statement. It's only four characters more to write in declarations, and will also have the good thing that it makes your code much clearer.

Comment: okay, thanks for the input. i dont think this would solve my problem though.

Comment: @TomFlan Why don't you try it? If it doesn't work then at least it's one thing to cross out as the possible error.

Comment: I did. with no luck. and you are right it is something to cross off the list. i might just try a whole different approach at comparing the bounding boxes. I have this project to hand in next week and already spent the whole day trying to solve 1 problem.

Comment: @TomFlan Get a good nights sleep, and you might see it all in a new light tomorrow. :)

Comment: aha thanks I shall be sure to do that! thanks for your help anyway